# Invalid index : Python - matplotlib pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

For the following code:

```
G = [
  [8.29187396e-04,4.98341625e-01,8.29187396e-04,4.98341625e-01,8.29187396e-04,8.29187396e-04],
  [4.99168745e-01,4.15627598e-04,2.49792186e-01,4.15627598e-04,2.49792186e-01,4.15627598e-04],
  [1.66666667e-01,1.66666667e-01,1.66666667e-01,1.66666667e-01,1.66666667e-01,1.66666667e-01],
  [6.65005537e-01,3.32779623e-01,5.53709856e-04,5.53709856e-04,5.53709856e-04,5.53709856e-04],
  [1.66666667e-01,1.66666667e-01,1.66666667e-01,1.66666667e-01,1.66666667e-01,1.66666667e-01],
  [1.65016502e-03,1.65016502e-03,1.65016502e-03,1.65016502e-03,9.91749175e-01,1.65016502e-03],
]

fnames = ['angelinajolie.html', 'bradpitt.html', 'jenniferaniston.html', 
  'jonvoight.html', 'martinscorcese.html', 'robertdeniro.html']

NX = len(fnames)
PI = random(NX)
PI /= sum(PI)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
evolution = [numpy.dot (PI, G**i) for i in xrange(1,20)]       

plt.figure()
for i in xrange(NX):
    plt.plot([step[0,i] for step in evolution], label=fnames[i], lw=2 )
    # ^ this line
#plt.draw


    IndexError: invalid index
```

Im getting this error. Im learning Python and Im not very familiar with the language. Googling this error didnt give any specific solutions. Wondering if someone can help.

Thanks

---

EDIT:

I tried the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
evolution = [numpy.dot (PI, G**i) for i in xrange(1,20)]
print 'xrange'
print xrange(1,20)
print ''
print 'evolution = '
print evolution
print ''


for i in xrange (NX):
print (step[0,i] for step in evolution)
```

And got this output:

```
xrange
xrange(1, 20)

 evolution = 
 [array([ 0.32804667,  0.21757686,  0.12538595,  0.15799482,  0.12910639,
     0.04188931]), array([ 0.16964679,  0.08472597,  0.02780032,  0.06486529,  0.0314962  ,
     0.00690881]), array([ 0.09553784,  0.03664288,  0.00636997,  0.03003363,   0.01003537,
     0.00115142]), array([ 0.05605324,  0.01678453,  0.00149546,  0.01458511,   0.00513061,
      0.0001919 ]), array([  3.37327444e-02,   7.93664097e-03,   3.57601326e-04,
       7.20471786e-03,   3.96276140e-03,   3.19838999e-05]), array([  2.06957198e-02,      3.82337165e-03,   8.66673387e-05,
       3.57980255e-03,   3.66208187e-03,   5.33064999e-06]), array([  1.29011406e-02,     1.86325141e-03,   2.12057110e-05,
       1.78219658e-03,   3.56712012e-03,   8.88441665e-07]), array([  8.15011563e-03,     9.14821461e-04,   5.22316873e-06,
       8.87848064e-04,   3.52188086e-03,   1.48073611e-07]), array([  5.20576887e-03,     4.51378732e-04,   1.29239804e-06,
       4.42402535e-04,   3.48893476e-03,   2.46789351e-08]), array([  3.35501606e-03,     2.23446508e-04,   3.20779482e-07,
       2.20459413e-04,   3.45918721e-03,   4.11315586e-09]), array([  2.17777263e-03,     1.10856782e-04,   7.97863000e-08,
       1.09862738e-04,   3.43040772e-03,   6.85525976e-10]), array([  1.42161006e-03,     5.50797457e-05,   1.98730096e-08,
       5.47489480e-05,   3.40204477e-03,   1.14254329e-10]), array([  9.32090403e-04,     2.73937246e-05,   4.95462506e-09,
       2.72836418e-05,   3.37396034e-03,   1.90423882e-11]), array([  6.13212265e-04,    1.36332014e-05,   1.23604372e-09,
      1.35965681e-05,   3.34611871e-03,   3.17373137e-12]), array([  4.04478562e-04,    6.78792560e-06,   3.08490244e-10,
      6.77573479e-06,   3.31850955e-03,   5.28955228e-13]), array([  2.67327741e-04,    3.38068736e-06,   7.70144829e-11,
      3.37663051e-06,   3.29112888e-03,   8.81592047e-14]), array([  1.76949431e-04,    1.68406555e-06,   1.92302878e-11,
      1.68271551e-06,   3.26397429e-03,   1.46932008e-14]), array([  1.17260538e-04,    8.39016441e-07,   4.80235424e-12,
      8.38567176e-07,   3.23704380e-03,   2.44886680e-15]), array([  7.77733433e-05,    4.18042435e-07,   1.19938700e-12,
      4.17892928e-07,   3.21033551e-03,   4.08144466e-16])]

     xrange(NX) = 
     xrange(6)
     <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10c1b9f50>
     <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10c1b9f50>
     <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10c1b9f50>
     <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10c1b9f50>
     <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10c1b9f50>
     <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10c1b9f50>
```

Comment: You will need to provide code that shows what `evolution` and `fnames` are.

Comment: Try replacing `plt.plot` call with a `print` that outputs `i` and parameters you pass to `plt.plot`. Run the loop, see if it works. If it does not, you will at least see the value of `i` when it last worked; it may help you. The example you provided works fine for me with plotting calls removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `i` is too large for either `step[0, i]` or `fnames[i]`.

In other words, the current value of `i` is not a valid index into one of those structures. Note that `i` can be anything between 0 and `NX - 1`.

You could try and print out the `step` values first, most likely they do not contain what you expect them to contain.

Comment: Oops: added it please see above

Comment: @MartijnPeters: did you try running the code? It worked for me for some reason.